# Efficient Querying of related Data in EF6

Tags: .net, entity-framework, xamarin

I have an complex object called TrainingProgram in my Model. A TrainingProgram consists (amongs others) of a collection of TrainingBlocks, which in turn hold collections of ExercisePairings. Each EercisePairing has a list of Exercises, plus some additional data (which is of no relevance here). I can query a program from the DB via EF6 by iterating through the dataset and explicitly loading everything into the context:

```
dbcontext.Entry(trainer).Collection(a => a.Programs).Load();
                        foreach (TrainingProgram p in trainer.Programs)
                        {
                            dbcontext.Entry(p).Collection(a => a.Blocks).Load();
                            foreach (TrainingBlock b in p.Blocks)
                            {
                                dbcontext.Entry(b).Collection(a => a.Circuits).Load();
                                foreach (ExercisePairing c in b.Circuits)
                                {
                                    dbcontext.Entry(c).Collection(a => a.Progressions).Load();
                                    foreach (var prog in c.Progressions)
                                    {
                                        dbcontext.Entry(prog).Reference(a => a.Exercise).Load();
                                        dbcontext.Entry(prog).Reference(a => a.Progression).Load();
                                    }

                                    dbcontext.Entry(c).Collection(a => a.Sets).Load();
                                    foreach (ExerciseSet s in c.Sets)
                                    {
                                        dbcontext.Entry(s).Reference(x => x.Exercise).Load();
                                        dbcontext.Entry(s.Exercise).Reference(x => x.Category).Load();
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
```

Obviously, this results in a ton of DB calls and hence, impaired efficiency. To solve this, I tried going the route of eager loading by using include and select, like so:

```
var pax = dbcontext.TrainingPrograms
                                .Include(x => x.Blocks.Select(xb => xb.Circuits.Select(xc => xc.Sets.Select(xs => xs.Exercise.Category))))
                                .Where(x => x.Id == p.Id)
                                .FirstOrDefault();
```

While this does return the related collections, it does so only partially. Namely, it only returns a single element in each collection, whereas in the iterative approach presented above, everything is returned just fine.

In all the documentation and tutorials I found, nested collections were never discussed. I'm convinced that there needs to be an elegant and efficient way to load my data, but can't seem to figure it out. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Take a look at the .ThenInclude method. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.entityframeworkqueryableextensions.theninclude?view=efcore-3.1

Comment: You would use it like .Include(...).ThenInclude(...).ThenInclude(...)  I would also check the sql in SSMS and make sure its what your wanting to do.

Comment: Thanks, Chris, but ThenInclude is EF Core. I'm on EF6.

Comment: @LukasPezenka Based on my search, i do not find more information for EF6 of Xamarin. You could use EF Core or sqlite instead. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/get-started/xamarin

Comment: @WendyZang-MSFT thank you. My client is built on Xamarin. The server is simply a .NET web API with MySql in the background. I'm sorry if my labeling was misleading.